# Intuition/geometric interpretation of this inequality with a constraint

Tags: inequality, optimization, intuition

$\arg \min_{x_j} \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{a_j^2}{x_j}$

s.t. $\sum_{j=1}^nx_j = 1$

$x_j \geq 0$

The solution is $x_k = \frac{|a_k|}{\sum_{j=1}^n|a_j|}$.

I'm wondering how to solve this optimization problem and if there's an intuitive interpretation, since the solution to $x_k$ is the proportion of $|a_j|$ in the sum of $|a_k|$.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. What does it mean "The solution might have an interpretation as proportion. Why is it?"

Comment: I'm wondering how to solve this optimization problem and if there's an intuitive interpretation, since the solution is the proportion of $|a_j|$ in the sum of $|a_k|$.

Comment: You are minimizing a function over the simplex?

Comment: Yes. Seems to be a regular optimization problem but I'm not familiar with it. I'm thinking if it's related to some common inequalities. Either way, any idea on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Construct the Lagrangian $$L(\mathbf{x},\lambda)=\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{a_j^2}{x_j}+\frac{\lambda}{2}(\sum_{j=1}^n x_j-1)$$
where $x_i\geq 0$ and $\lambda\in \mathbb{R}$. Then $$L^{'}_{x_j}=-\frac{a_j^2}{2x_j^2}+\frac{\lambda}{2}\longrightarrow \\ L^{'}_{x_j} = 0 \iff x_j^2=\frac{a_j^2}{\lambda}$$
There are two possible **postive** roots to the last equation, and they depend on whether $\sqrt{\lambda}$ is positive or negative. But in order to have $\sum_{j=1}^n x_j=1$, we need $\sqrt{\lambda}$ to be non-negative as well. Therefore we get that $$x_j=\frac{|a_j|}{\sqrt{\lambda}}$$

Plugging in $\sqrt{\lambda}=\sum_{j=1}^n |a_j|$ gives the solution $$x_j=\frac{|a_j|}{\sum_{j=1}^n |a_j|}$$
and it easy to verify that it satisfies KKT conditions, and since the problem is convex we have found the minimum point.